# Rails - Creating a record in a join model but with an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, attributes, insert

I have a Join Model I just Migrated called EventUsers that has an user_id, event_id, and an attribute i created called opinion:string

```
  create_table :events_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :event_id
      t.string :opinion #  extra attribute I made
  end
```

and 
event.rb

```
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

and user.rb

```
   has_and_belongs_to_many :events
```

I can add to the join model with

```
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @user.events << @event
```

but before I do that...... How do I set the opinion attribute to some string and then insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your join model has any fields other than just the foreign keys, then you shouldn't be using a HABTM relationship. You should create an intermediate model such as Opinion and have each model related like so:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :opinions
  has_many :users, :through => :opinions
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :opinions
  has_many :events, :through => :opinions
end

class Opinion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Update:

In order to add opinions, you will likely want to create a RESTful interface. I would start by adding a nested route within either users, events, or both

```
map.resources :users do |user|
  user.resources :opinions
end
```

Then add an opinions controller with your standard RESTful actions (new, create, edit, update, etc) and corresponding views. There are tons of resources on how to build a standard restful interface, but I would start with these:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: What is Choice and how are you using it?

Comment: I had created a model called Love, but there was an error singularizing Love into Lofe which threw the uninitialized constant error.  I then created a model called Personal.... where the personal.rb =>  (belongs_to :user ; belongs_to :event) and user.rb => (has_many :personals ;   has_many :events, :through => :personals) and event.rb => (  has_many :personals ; has_many :users, :through => :personals ) But I keep getting the attribute (:opinion) as unknown attribute error.  any ideas?

Comment: Personal << @user.events.create(:opinion => 'love') still gets the unknown attribute

Comment: How familiar with RESTful resources/interfaces are you? I updated my answer to help a little, but this is definitely the way you want to go. There are tons of resources out there and people on SO will definitely be able to help out as you need it.